# magnetic force from v=0 and dB changing

Tags: magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

magnetic force is defined as:

$ \mathbf{F}=q \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$

so if v=0 there is no force. However Faraday's law states that if $d\mathbf{B}\neq0 $ then we have an induced emf even though speed of q in a circle is 0 and the magnetic force is not moving. Does this mean that for every scenario where we increase B and everything else is static in our system and we have q that can move in our system the emf is changing? If not what are the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz force for the magnetic field $\vec F$=q$\vec v\times\vec B$ states that if you have a charge q moving in a region in which there is a magnetic field, then a force proportional to the speed of the charge acts on it. Correctly if $ v=0$, then $F=0$.
I don't understand what you mean with "the magnetic force is not moving" (how a force can move?), but according to Faraday-Neumann laws we have that
\begin{equation}
\notag
\vec \nabla \times \vec E =-\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}\ .
\end{equation}
This means that if you have a magnetic field which is changing in time, then an electric field is induced, and this field is non conservative!
So if you have the charge q which is not moving and you turn on a magnetic field (so you make a variation of this one), then the charge will move but not because of the magnetic field. The moving of the charge is due to the electric field induced by the variation of the magnetic one.